# Tethering / Portable Wifi Hotspot Samsung Captivate

Tags: samsung, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

Repeated attempts to get WIFI tethering failed, even after a reboot. I can turn on the wifi hotspot. I used these steps.

1. Settings > Wireless & networks > More... > Tethering & portable
   hotspot > Set up Wi-Fi hotspot,
2. (put in my settings - SSID, security "WPA2 PSK", and password)
3. Save
4. Check "Portable Wi-Fi hotspot"

At this point the hotspot turns on and is discover-able by other devices, but when they connect to the hotspot, they can't access the internet.
Anyone have a solution to this? Am I doing something wrong? Need this fixed before I travel...
TIA

Here's my device details:

> Samsung Captivate
>
> Device Model: SGH-I897
>
> Android version: 4.1.2 Jelly Bean
>
> CyanogenMod version: 10.0.0-captivatemtd

EDIT: Ok, I got it working. I connected my laptop using USB tethering, which worked immediately on the first try. Once I had done that I disconnected from USB and tried enabling the portable hotspot again. This time, connected devices could use the internet via the hotspot.

Hope this helps other people.

Comment: Maybe you convert your edit into an answer, and accept it (after the forced 2-day-delay) -- so people can see it's solved even in the questions' lists?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

I connected my laptop using USB tethering, which worked immediately on the first try. Once I had done that I disconnected from USB and tried enabling the portable hotspot again. This time, connected devices could use the internet via the hotspot.